# Type mismatch: inferred type is Context? but Context was expected - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting above mentioned issue after updating kotlin version to 1.3.0

Below is the code,

```
     public class SequenceLayout(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int)
: FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
```

}

First line I am getting that. issue . Pls help me to solve this.

Comment: remove ? from context

Answer (score 3):

The signature is wrong. Context can't be null to create the view, while `AttributeSet` can. Change it like

```
 public class SequenceLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin `Type` is different type than `Type?`. The second one is Nullable. To first one you cannot assign `null` value.

Whenever you expect `Type?` you can use `Type`, but there is no way to use it in opposite way.

This way Kotlin ensure null safety. More you can read here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

So, how to solve your problem?:

- Use `!!` operator - this operator will convert nullable type to notnullable, but, if value is null you'll get `NullPointerException`
- Change signature of your function to use compatible types. In your case this looks like proper way.